# How can I get the owner and group owner account name of a file in macOS using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, macos

I'm migrating from Object-C to .NET 7.

The Object-C using `NSFileManager` with `fileAttributesAtPath` to get the owner and group owner account name of a file.

In .NET 7, I tried to use `FileInfo` with `GetAccessControl` but it only works on Windows.

I also tried using `PInvoke`:

```
[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation")]
extern static IntPtr NSFileManager();
```

But it said:

> Unhandled exception. System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to
> find an entry point named 'NSFileManager' in shared library
> '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation'

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I added [tag:macos] as I assume you want to get the access control info for an apple desktop device? If not add the appropriate O/S tag to your question.

Comment: P/Invoke is for calling exported C functions. `NSFileManager` is an ObjC interface. Maybe you're looking for [How to PInvoke AppKit methods from .Net Core application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665544/how-to-pinvoke-appkit-methods-from-net-core-application)